# Wait myTable.draw()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and have a (I hope, simple) question.
I have two functions: myFunc1() and myFunc2() in this code:

```
myFunc1(); //display start_wait.gif
myTable.draw(); 
myFunc2(); //display finish_wait.gif
```

myTable.draw() (Datatables's instruction) is very slow (about 15 sec) and myFunc2() start before myTable.draw() finishes.

Have you got a solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `drawCallback`: https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback, or you could hook an event handler to the `draw` event: https://datatables.net/reference/event/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps.

My case is to reload or after search on a table then see if there is any value. else I want to display a popup.

I did this:

Datatable settup:

```
"drawCallback": function () {
                var event = $.extend($.Event('datatableDraw'), this); //Assign a custom event to the document.
                $(document).trigger(event);  //fire it.
            }
```

Then the function that calls the draw method.

```
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    var myCallback = function (table) {
       //the code you want to execute after the draw happends.
       //display popup if you want.
    }
    $(document).one('datatableDraw',myCallback) //this will listen for the custom event, and get execute only once.
    table.search(kwd).draw();
```

a little bit tricky but works.

Comment: Nice! DataTable event is `"draw.dt"`;

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the draw event: 

From doc: "Draw event - fired once the table has completed a draw."

then call myFunc2() in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

On your dataTable Definition add drawCallback which will call myFunc2();

```
var myTable = $('#YourTable').dataTable( {
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
 myFunc2();
}} );


myFunc1(); //display start_wait.gif

myTable.draw();
```